# Apache2 fail "start"

Tags: apache2, xampp

Hello everyone I wish you help me. My problem that apache 2 not running, in spite of I wrote command `service apache2 start` or `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.

When I enter in localhost I saw this

[image]

and he gave me on terminal this :

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 0.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
                                                                         [fail]
 * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
```

Comment: Port 80 is already in use. To check which process is using it use `sudo lsof -i :80`. Regarding the screenshot I guess it is `lighttpd`.

Answer (score 3):

Port 80 is already in use by lighttpd web server.(netstat -an | grep :80)

**Stop lighttpd:**

```
/etc/init.d/lighttpd stop
```

or

```
service lighttpd stop
```

see if lighttpd process is running or not:

```
ps -ef |grep "lighttpd"
```

if yes, Kill manually

```
kill -9 Process_ID
```

**start apache2**

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

or

```
service apache2 start
```